# Testing a js function with Jest returns a bad value in for loop

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

It is my first use of Jest and I try to test a function with many many values like this :

```js
const convertConfig = require('../tools/convertNumWord/config');
const numToWordConstructor = require('../tools/convertNumWord/num2words/numToWords');
const wordToNumConstructor = require('../tools/convertNumWord/words2num/wordsToNum');

describe('EN-CONFIG', () => {
  const config = convertConfig['en'];  // It returns an object with configuration values for the language
  const numToWord = numToWordConstructor(config); // It return a function builds with config object 
  const wordToNum = wordToNumConstructor(config);

  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    it(`Test for value ${i}`, () => {
      expect(wordToNum(numToWord(i))).toBe(Number(i));
    });
  }
});
```

Jest returns this error :

```sh
 ● ENGLISH CONFIG › Test for value 2

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

      69 |   for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      70 |     it(`Test for value ${i}`, () => {
    > 71 |       expect(wordToNum(numToWord(i))).toBe(Number(i));
         |                                       ^
      72 |     });
      73 |   }
      74 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/loopConvertNum.test.js:71:39)

  ● ENGLISH CONFIG › Test for value 3

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 3
    Received: 1

      69 |   for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      70 |     it(`Test for value ${i}`, () => {
    > 71 |       expect(wordToNum(numToWord(i))).toBe(Number(i));
         |                                       ^
      72 |     });
      73 |   }
      74 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/loopConvertNum.test.js:71:39)

  ● ENGLISH CONFIG › Test for value 4

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 4
    Received: 1

      69 |   for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      70 |     it(`Test for value ${i}`, () => {
    > 71 |       expect(wordToNum(numToWord(i))).toBe(Number(i));
         |                                       ^
      72 |     });
      73 |   }
      74 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/loopConvertNum.test.js:71:39)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       3 failed, 1 todo, 3 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.773s
Ran all test suites.
```

My first test worked but for 2 days, Jest does not seem to execute my function for each round of the for loop, as if it kept value in memory (often that of the second round of the loop) and the toBe test is ultimately false. In some cases, the result of my functions is completely inconsistent (null or some kind of increment from the previous result). When I launch my function with the node with the same arguments it works well.

I tried with it.each and the problem persists. Each mode is not good for me because I want to test my function for many many many values .

After your feedback, here are the two functions imported and the config constant. **But these functions work well with the arguments sent in my loop. The problem does not seem to come from what returns the functions because when I launch them individually with node they work well with the same arguments as in the for loop of my Jest test.**

This is the function imported in **numToWordConstructor** :

```js
    const config = require('../config');
const _ = require('lodash');

const numToWordsConstructor = config => {
  config = _.cloneDeep(config);
  const letters = {
    ..._.invertBy(config.oneDigits),
    ..._.invertBy(config.doubleDigits),
    ..._.invertBy(config.tripleDigits),
  };
  const hundredWords = config.hundredWords;
  const oneDigits = config.oneDigits;
  const doubleDigits = config.doubleDigits;
  const tripleDigits = config.isEachHundredsWords ? config.tripleDigits : null;
  const separators = config.separators;

  let words = [];

  // Convertion function
  const num2Words = number => {
    let result = '';

    const numbersWords = Object.keys(letters);
    const nbString = number.toString();
    const nb = parseFloat(nbString.replace(/ /gi, ''));

    if (nb > 999999999999)
      throw new Error(
        'Function numToWords for number',
        number,
        ': Number to big',
      );
    if (isNaN(nb))
      throw new Error(
        'Function numToWords for number',
        number,
        'Not a valid number',
      );

    if (Math.ceil(nb) != nb) {
      separateFloatNumbers = nbString.split('.');
      return (
        num2Words(separateFloatNumbers[0]) +
        ' virgule ' +
        num2Words(separateFloatNumbers[1])
      );
    }

    if (Number(number) === 0) return oneDigits[0][0];

    // Build numByThousand object to split number to 3 digits arrays
    let numByThousand = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]];

    if (numbersWords.includes(nbString)) {
      result = letters[nbString][0];
    } else {
      const nbReversedDigits = nbString
        .split('')
        .map(digit => parseInt(digit))
        .reverse();

      numByThousand = numByThousand
        .map(thousand => {
          if (nbReversedDigits.length >= 3) {
            return (thousand = nbReversedDigits.splice(0, 3).reverse());
          } else {
            return (thousand = [0, 0, 0]
              .map(
                defaultDigit =>
                  nbReversedDigits.splice(0, 1)[0] || defaultDigit,
              )
              .reverse());
          }
        })
        .reverse();
    }

    // Build array of words depending of numByThousand
    const convertNumByThousandToWords = numByThousand => {
      const hundred = numByThousand[0] * 100;
      const ten = numByThousand[1] * 10 + numByThousand[2];
      const newWords = [];

      if (numByThousand[0] > 0) {
        if (config.isEachHundredsWords) {
          newWords.push(tripleDigits[hundred][0]);
        } else if (numByThousand[0] === 1 && !config.isOneBeforeOnlyOne[0]) {
          newWords.push(config.hundredWords[0]);
        } else {
          newWords.push(oneDigits[numByThousand[0]][0]);
          newWords.push(config.hundredWords[0]);
        }
      }
      if (ten > 0) {
        if (Object.keys(doubleDigits).includes(ten.toString())) {
          newWords.push(doubleDigits[ten][0]);
          return newWords;
        } else {
          if (numByThousand[1] > 0)
            newWords.push(doubleDigits[numByThousand[1] * 10][0]);
          if (numByThousand[2] > 0)
            newWords.push(oneDigits[numByThousand[2]][0]);
          return newWords;
        }
      }
      return newWords;
    };

    if (config.noMoreMillionSeparator) separators.push(config.separators[0]);
    numByThousand.map((thousand, i) => {
      if (thousand.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur) > 0) {
        words = _.concat(words, convertNumByThousandToWords(thousand));
        // Handle thousand separators
        separators[config.separators.length - i - 1] &&
          words.push(separators[config.separators.length - i - 1][0]);
      }
    });

    //Handle specifics spelling rules
    words = config.spellingRules(words, oneDigits, doubleDigits);

    // console.log('words : ', words.join(' '));
    return words.join(' ');
  };

  return num2Words;
};

module.exports = numToWordsConstructor;
```

This is the function imported in **wordToNumConstructor** :

```js
    const _ = require('lodash');

    const arrayAwareInvert = obj => {
      return _.reduce(
        obj,
        (result, values, key) => {
          return _.reduce(
            values,
            (result, value) => {
              result[value] = key;
              return result;
            },
            result,
          );
        },
        {},
      );
    };

    const word2numConstructor = config => {
      config = _.cloneDeep(config);
      const separators = config.separators;
      const hundredWords = config.hundredWords;
      const oneDigits = arrayAwareInvert(config.oneDigits);
      const doubleDigits = arrayAwareInvert(config.doubleDigits);
      const tripleDigits = config.isEachHundredsWords
        ? arrayAwareInvert(config.tripleDigits)
        : null;
      const oneDigitsWords = Object.values(config.oneDigits).reduce(
        (acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur),
        [],
      );
      const doubleDigitsWords = Object.values(config.doubleDigits).reduce(
        (acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur),
        [],
      );
      const tripleDigitsWords = Object.values(config.tripleDigits).reduce(
        (acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur),
        [],
      );

      return stringNumber => {
        separators.forEach(thousandSeparators =>
          thousandSeparators.forEach(separator => {
            // Remove spaces from separator's word in sentence to not split it with split(' ') later
            const regex = new RegExp(`${separator}`, 'gi');
            stringNumber = stringNumber.replace(
              regex,
              separator.split(' ').join(''),
            );
            // Remove spaces from separator's word
            return separator.split(' ').join('');
          }),
        );

        let thousandsWords = [];
        if (config.noMoreMillionSeparator) {
          thousandsWords = separators[0];
        } else {
          thousandsWords = _.flatten(separators);
        }

        stringNumber.trim();
        // Apply on stringNumber the rules of locale key of config object
        stringNumber = config.rulesOnSentence(stringNumber);

        // Apply lowerCase on stringNumber and split words at each spaces
        let words = stringNumber.toLowerCase().split(' ');
        // Apply on each words the rules of locale key of config object
        words = config.rulesOnWords(words);

        const convertWordsByThousandToNumber = wordsByThousand => {
          return wordsByThousand.map(values => {
            if (values.length === 0) return 0;
            let thousand = null;
            let temp;
            // Function to handle ten and unit if temp is hundred value
            const handleTen_Unit = (i, coef = 100) => {
              if (!values[i] || thousandsWords.includes(values[i])) {
                thousand = temp * coef;
              } else if (oneDigitsWords.includes(values[i])) {
                thousand = temp * coef + Number(oneDigits[values[i]]);
              } else if (doubleDigitsWords.includes(values[i])) {
                if (!values[i + 1] || thousandsWords.includes(values[i + 1])) {
                  thousand = temp * coef + Number(doubleDigits[values[i]]);
                } else if (oneDigitsWords.includes(values[i + 1])) {
                  thousand =
                    temp * coef +
                    Number(doubleDigits[values[i]]) +
                    Number(oneDigits[values[i + 1]]);
                }
              }
            };

            //Convert values
            if (values.length === 1 && thousandsWords.includes(values[0])) {
              thousand = 1;
            } else if (hundredWords.includes(values[0])) {
              temp = 1;
              handleTen_Unit(1);
            } else if (doubleDigitsWords.includes(values[0])) {
              temp = Number(doubleDigits[values[0]]);
              if (!values[1] || thousandsWords.includes(values[1])) {
                thousand = temp;
              } else if (oneDigitsWords.includes(values[1])) {
                thousand = temp + Number(oneDigits[values[1]]);
              }
            } else if (oneDigitsWords.includes(values[0])) {
              temp = Number(oneDigits[values[0]]);
              if (!values[1] || thousandsWords.includes(values[1])) {
                thousand = temp;
              } else if (hundredWords.includes(values[1])) {
                handleTen_Unit(2);
              } else {
                thousand = temp;
              }
            } else if (tripleDigitsWords.includes(values[0])) {
              temp = Number(tripleDigits[values[0]]);
              if (!values[1] || thousandsWords.includes(values[1])) {
                thousand = temp;
              } else {
                handleTen_Unit(1, 1);
              }
            }

            return thousand;
          });
        };

        const buildWordsByThousand = words => {
          const wordsByThousand = [];
          separators
            .slice(0) // Make a shallow copy
            .reverse()
            .map(thousandSeparators => {
              const index = _.findIndex(words, word =>
                thousandSeparators.includes(word),
              );
              index > -1
                ? wordsByThousand.push(words.splice(0, index + 1))
                : wordsByThousand.push([]);
            });
          wordsByThousand.push(words); // Push the rest of words for hundred's part
          return wordsByThousand;
        };

        let results = [];

        let indexOfMillionWords = -1;
        words.map((word, i) => {
          if (separators[1].includes(word)) indexOfMillionWords = i;
        });

        if (config.noMoreMillionSeparator && indexOfMillionWords >= 0) {
          const wordsAboveMillion = words.splice(indexOfMillionWords + 1);
          const wordsOverMillion = words.splice(0, words.length - 1);
          const wordsByThousandOverMillion = buildWordsByThousand(
            wordsOverMillion,
          ).splice(1); // Splice is necessary to remove array of million thousand part
          const wordsByThousandAboveMillion = buildWordsByThousand(
            wordsAboveMillion,
          ).splice(1); // Splice is necessary to remove array of million thousand part
          results = results.concat(
            convertWordsByThousandToNumber(wordsByThousandOverMillion),
          );
          results = results.concat(
            convertWordsByThousandToNumber(wordsByThousandAboveMillion),
          );
        } else {
          const wordsByThousand = buildWordsByThousand(words);
          results = results.concat(convertWordsByThousandToNumber(wordsByThousand));
        }

        results;
        return results
          .reverse()
          .reduce(
            (acc, cur, i) =>
              acc === null || cur === null ? null : acc + cur * Math.pow(1000, i),
            0,
          );
      };
    };

    module.exports = word2numConstructor;
```

And this is the result of **const config = convertConfig['en']** :

```js
{
    rulesOnSentence: sentence => {
      // Write your rules's function to apply on sentence before splitted it
      return sentence
        .normalize('NFD')
        .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
        .replace(/[\-]/g, ' ')
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '');
    },
    rulesOnWords: words => {
      // Write your rules's function to apply on words array (after to have splitted sentence)
      return words.filter(word => word !== 'and');
    },
    spellingRules: (words, oneDigits, doubleDigits) => {
      const unit = _.flatten(Object.values(oneDigits).slice(1));
      const ten = _.flatten(
        [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90].map(num => doubleDigits[num]),
      );
      const newWords = [...words];
      let j = 0;
      words.forEach((word, i) => {
        // Hyphenate all compound numbers
        if (ten.includes(word) && unit.includes(words[i + 1])) {
          newWords.splice(i - j, 2, word + '-' + words[i + 1]);
          j++;
        }
      });
      return newWords;
    },
    noMoreMillionSeparator: false,
    separators: [
      ['thousand', 'thousands'],
      ['million', 'millions'],
      ['billion', 'billions'],
    ],
    hundredWords: ['hundred', 'hundreds'],
    isOneBeforeOnlyOne: [true, true, true, true],
    isEachHundredsWords: false,
    tripleDigits: {},
    oneDigits: {
      0: ['zero'],
      1: ['one'],
      2: ['two'],
      3: ['three'],
      4: ['four'],
      5: ['five'],
      6: ['six'],
      7: ['seven'],
      8: ['eight'],
      9: ['nine'],
    },
    doubleDigits: {
      10: ['ten'],
      11: ['eleven'],
      12: ['twelve'],
      13: ['thirteen'],
      14: ['fourteen'],
      15: ['fifteen'],
      16: ['sixteen'],
      17: ['seventeen'],
      18: ['eighteen'],
      19: ['nineteen'],
      20: ['twenty'],
      30: ['thirty'],
      40: ['forty'],
      50: ['fifty'],
      60: ['sixty'],
      70: ['seventy'],
      80: ['eighty'],
      90: ['ninety'],
    },
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable feedback.

Comment: The problem is in your code. That you don't separate wordToNum and numToWord tests is a bad testing practice because this doesn't allow to easily determine which of them failed. These functions are stateful, at least because of `words` array. *Jest does not seem to execute my function for each round of the for loop, as if it kept value in memory* - Jest doesn't and can't do anything like that, but your code does. That you assign wordToNum and numToWord once and not inside beforeEach potentially result in test cross-contamination. You probably wouldn't see this error if beforeEach were used.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you. I can't separate my tests for each function because if I want to test for 1000 values I have to write all results of numToWord manually... 
Ok thank you for the "stateful" lead because I believe it is this. The configuration variable are modifying by the first loop.
"Jest doesn't and can't do anything like that, but your code does" : Thank you for this information but I didn't see the source code of Jest function and I don't know if there isn't cache values.
I think I will find the solution with your answer !!!!
Thank you very much !

Comment: If Jest would cache function calls, that would make it completely useless for testing anything. Usually in unit testing the goal isn't to test *all* possible combinations, just a few expected ones and the edge cases. If it works for 42 you can assume that it works for 43 as well. So you could test e.g. 0, 1, 2, 10, 100, 1.5, -1, ... etc and the invalid values. That would give a much more reliable testing result than just confirming that the two functions cancel each other out, which tells you nothing about how well they actually work.

Comment: I don't mean that you should type values manually. In this case I'd likely end up with fixture file that contains number and string pairs, then test wordToNum  and numToWord separately against it. A fixture likely can be generated from their output and validated by a human once. Since you know that statefulness can make it work differently, it likely should be covered in tests. Having two test suites with both beforeEach and without it would probably be a safe move.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But, my functions have to work for any values for any language in config object. So, if wordTonum(numToWord(i)) work for 42 I can't assume that it works for 43 because there is may be a spellingRules or a string 
pre-processing rule (rulesOnSentence or rulesOnWords). I have to test all the possibilities on number sections according to my algorithm because each language can have its own specificity on one or more numbers or section of numbers.

Comment: I have already managed to test all the values ​​from 0 to 100,000 and from 100,000 to 100 billion with steps of 100,000 then 1 million in 120 seconds but the problem actually appeared when I wanted to refactor my code and it is surely due to "stateful".

Thank you for your clarification 

Comment: But if there's a problem with the rules your test won't catch it because the functions cancel each other out.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 other .test.js files for each function that test some values to know where the error come from.

So, you would not have used Jest to perform the test on values sections (which is not intended to target an error in my function but to highlight a conversion error in one direction or in the other) ? This test has already allowed me to correct many special cases when it worked but it may not be the right way to do it.
In any case, thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my functions are stateful and the results of the second test are cross-contaminated by the first test.
Thank you to Estus Flask (you can see more details in comments).

This test work good :

```js
describe('ENGLISH CONFIG', () => {
  let config, numToWord, wordToNum;

  beforeEach(() => {
    config = convertConfig['en'];
    numToWord = numToWordConstructor(config);
    wordToNum = wordToNumConstructor(config);
  });

  for (let i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) {
    it(`Test for value `, () => {
      expect(wordToNum(numToWord(i))).toBe(i);
    });
  }
});
```

I will work on my functions so that they do not modify the variables of closure (in constructor) .

EDIT :
Better keep my first jest function (faster) and just put the variable *words*

```js
let words = []; // line 17 of numToWords function
```

inside the returned function of constructor  :

```js
// [...]
const tripleDigits = config.isEachHundredsWords ? config.tripleDigits : null;
const separators = config.separators;

// Convertion function
const num2Words = number => {
  let words = [];
  let result = '';
// [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the loop inside the `it` block.

```js
  it('convert range of 1..4 to word and back to number', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      expect(wordToNum(numToWord(i))).toBe(i);
    }
  });
```

Also remove `Number()` the iterator `i` is already a number.

If this doesn't work you might need to post the function body of `wordToNum` & `numToWord`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The number was a test residue.
I tried with for loop inside but same problem.